# Use onClick to change path in a non-Router component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React app with following simplified structure:

```
function App(props) {
    return (
        <Navbar />
        <Router>
            <Route exact path="/profile/" component={Profile} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Router>
    );
}
```

In `Navbar` component I have a button for `logout`, meaning that I need to:

1. Delete Authentication token from Storage (simply do a logic for general case), and
2. Route user to the login page.

I tried to use `onClick` of that button and use `this.props.history.push('/')` to change the path, but this doesn't work (it complains that `history` is `undefined`), since my navbar is defined outside the Router.

My question is, is it okay to move `Navbar` to inside of my Router components and repeat it while it is the same in all of pages? Or is there any duplicate-proof solution I can use to change my browser path?

Comment: I think it is fine to put it inside the router, i dont think Navbar will rerender if the route changed.

Comment: Thanks, your mention about Navbar not being rendered on changing route helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes listen to the history api provided by the Router context and since `Navbar` is rendered outside of it they don't reflect the change.

The solution is to wrap Router around navbar and also render NAvbar as a default route

```
function App(props) {
    return (
       <Router>
          <>
            <Route component={Navbar}/>
            <Route exact path="/profile/" component={Profile} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          </>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted your answer (I'd be happy if I know what's wrong here), but I ended up with a similar solution to pass `Route`'s `props` to my `Navbar` to have `history` access: `<Route render={(props) => (<Nabvar {...props} />)} />`

Comment: @AliTou, Rendering Navbar as a Route is required so that the Router Props are available to it

Comment: Yeah, this is what other answers didn't consider.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine to insert `<Navbar>` into the Router. My setup tends to be

```
<Router>
    <div className="app-container">
      <Navigation />
      <div className="content">
        <Switch>
          (Routes go here)
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: How can I access `history` inside `Navigation` now? I is undefined for me. (Should I pass any `props` to `Navigation`?

Comment: Use the `useHistory` hook.

Comment: If `Navbar` is not a function component, what can I do?

Comment: You can use the `withRouter()` function, then use with `this.props.history`. More info here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score 2):

Yes!
Try using `<Switch>`in router and `<Link>` inside your Navbar

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
        // inside Navbar try using <Link to="/">Logout</Link>
        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch> 
    </Router>
  );
}
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Can I access to `history` object in `Navbar` now? Because I don't want to use `Link` to simply redirect to home, I want to also clear my Authentication in Storage.

Comment: Since u r using function component, you can try const { history } = useHistory(); then u can access the history without any problem. Give it a try.

Comment: @WesleyLoh Thanks. In this case, did I ever need to include `Navbar` in `Router`?